# How can i bring the output format (dd-MM-yyyy) with the datatype date in pyspark? also Checked using to_date but it prints default format(yyyy-MM-dd)

Tags: pyspark

to_date function doesn't works for the format dd-MM-yyyy.Either it is going blank in output with the datatye as date or it prints the output with the correct format with the datatype string.I need the output with the format of dd-MM-yyyy with the datatype as date.so basically,i need output in dd-MM-yyyy format with date datatype.In the above image,it is giving o/p in yyyy-MM-dd format.Kindly help.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("12-06-2023",)], ["input_date"])
df = df.withColumn("output_date",F.to_date(df.input_date,"dd-MM-yyyy"))
df.show()
type(df)
```

Comment: in spark, only `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format is considered as `DateType`. all other formats are `StringType`. Use `to_date(<dateCol>, <inputFormat>)` to convert a string date to `DateType`. and, `date_format(<dateCol>, <desiredFormat>)` to get a string date of the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with PySpark, I am executing this example with Spark 3.4 and Python 3.11.

Spark `to_date` function to convert String to Date format of a DataFrame column.

So, I tried `date_format` function to convert the date into your required format.
But, `date_format` function return data type is `string` . When I tried to convert output `date_format` to `date` data type it is returning `null`.

So, as of now my understanding is we can not convert it to date datatype. I am trying other alternatives.

**Here is PySpark Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date,date_format
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("12-06-2023",)], ["input_date"])
df.show()
#+----------+
#|input_date|
#+----------+
#|12-06-2023|
#+----------+
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- input_date: string (nullable = true)
 
df2 = df.withColumn("output_date",date_format(F.to_date(df.input_date,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy'))
df2.show()
#+----------+-----------+
#|input_date|output_date|
#+----------+-----------+
#|12-06-2023| 12-06-2023|
#+----------+-----------+

df2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- input_date: string (nullable = true)
# |-- output_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: have tried using UDF - strptime function as well but the same format(yyyy-MM-dd) is populating as output